# kbd_event not correct work on some GDIs

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, focus, ui-automation, sendkeys

I am trying to send key to IE address bar. I open web page on IE but when I send key to that it removes previous content of address bar.
How to send string to IE address bar or search box ?

Comment: We could probably provide you with better help if you edited your question to include more details. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What kind of application have you created? Why are you trying to send individual keys to the IE address bar? Are you trying to automate web browsing? I suspect there's a better solution; automation like this is tricky.

Comment: Also, what are GDIs (in your title)?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, when you send a key to the address bar, it's going to remove what's already displayed there. The same thing happens if you press a key on the physical keyboard. The reason is that the text in the address bar is *selected* (or highlighted), meaning that everything gets erased when you type even so much as a single key. It's intended for convenience, but obviously getting in your way here.

You need to *deselect* the text in the address bar first before sending the key press.

Also note that the [`kbd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304.aspx) function has been superseded by [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx), which you might want to use instead.

Comment: yes , tnx for corrcet answer but why really keyboard do it , previous chars is deselected . i can't kill focus because i need this for send other key . i can send click to text box but previous char is selected and removed too . do you have suggestion for deselect previous chars??? tnx

Comment: @joli: I didn't say to kill the focus, I said to *deselect* the text. Alternatively, get a copy of the currently selected text in a local string variable, append your character(s) to it, and then send that text back to the address bar's textbox. It will replace everything there, but that's okay, because you've already included it.

Comment: i see microsoft osk and OS on keys click isn't change focus . how do it?  click event by default changed click .

Comment: @joli: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. The window for the On-Screen Keyboard utility refuses to accept the focus, but that doesn't have anything to do with the way that a textbox (such as the address bar) gets the focus.

Comment: tnx . your answer is correct but how can i write a program that refuses to accept the focus . i try to the get position of user click by a mouse hook . maybe i can break continuum of mouse hook by not calling `CallNextHookEx` and prevent of send mouse event to kernel when user clicked on my OSK.

Comment: @joli: Oh, are you actually writing your own on-screen keyboard? It's not all that difficult to prevent it from ever getting the focus. The first trick is specifying the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` extended window style when you create the window (add it to the `dwExStyle` parameter when you call the [`CreateWindowEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680.aspx)). As the documentation indicates, this will prevent Windows from bringing the window to the foreground. But it doesn't prevent queue activation when the user clicks on the window.

Comment: (continued) To do that, you need to handle the [`WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645612.aspx), and return the appropriate value. Again, as the table in the documentation shows, you'll probably want to return `MA_NOACTIVATE`, which does not activate the window, but allows processing of the mouse message. That'll ensure that the button the user clicks on actually *receives* the click event, but it also prevents your window from stealing the focus. (You can also check out how this works yourself by using Spy++ to watch the messages received by Windows OSK.)

Comment: yes it is useful but i don't access to `CreateWindowEx` or WndProc . in fact i am using java (jna wrapper for win32 api) and javafx for my osk. is there an other solution for no active my window such as send message or any other api?

Comment: @joli: This is why you should include as much detail as possible in your question. I have no way of knowing that you're using a Java wrapper; the way you asked the question, I assumed you were writing a C or C++ app targeting the Win32 API directly. No, you need to process Windows messages. You can do without setting the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` style, but you need to find a way to handle `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`. I've never used Java, nor that wrapper lib, but I can only imagine it has some facility for processing Windows messages. A wrapper for the WinAPI *has* to expose WndProc to be useful.

Comment: can i change window style after create it with the API such as `SetWindowLongPtr` ?? and set WS_EX_NOACTIVATE

Comment: @joli: Yes, you can call [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591.aspx) (or `SetWindowLongPtr` if you're compiling for 64-bit) to modify the extended style flags. Specify `GWL_EXSTYLE` for the `nIndex` parameter, and then add the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` flag. That still doesn't solve your primary issue though, of how to process the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message. Check the documentation for the library you're using.

Comment: i use mouse hook for getting the position of mouse clicks and i have the size of main window of my OSK and with this way can understand clicks on that , in this state i can call `SetWindowLong` for add WS_EX_NOACTIVATE . but i am not sure on click (WM_LBUTTONDOWN , WM_RBUTTONDOWN ,...) OS send WM_MOUSEACTIVATE to my window.

Comment: @joli: Yeah, the point of handling `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` is not so that you can determine when the user clicked on your window. It's so that you can return the value `MA_NOACTIVATE`, which tells Windows not to activate your window, even though the user clicked on it. By default, a click will *always* bring a window to the foreground. This is how you explicitly tell Windows you want a different behavior. Yes, where ever you handle `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is going to be the sample place you handle `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deselect a text and append something to the end of it, try sending the End key press first, with the help of kbd_event/SendInput.